# Change Url inside Array

Tags: php, arrays, regex, wordpress

In wordpress I am using a plugin that automatically generates thumbnail from the first image url in the post.

The url of the images are:

```
[IMG]http://imagehost.com/images/1234567890123456_thumb.jpg[/IMG] //thumbnails in post
```

For the plugin does not generate a thumbnail from that mini image I need to change inside the array the urls for

```
[IMG]http://imagehost.com/images/1234567890123456.jpg[/IMG] //Original image in image host
```

In other words I need to remove `_thumb` of the urls inside the array.

The code generator thumbnails is:

```
// Initialize variable used to store list of matched images as per provided regular expression
$matches = array();

// Get all images from post's body
preg_match_all('/\[img\]([^\[\]>]*)/i', $post[0]->post_content, $matches);

if (count($matches)) {
    foreach ($matches[0] as $key => $image) {
        /**
         * If the image is from wordpress's own media gallery, then it appends the thumbmail id to a css class.
         * Look for this id in the IMG tag.
         */
        preg_match('/wp-image-([\d]*)/i', $image, $thumb_id);
        $thumb_id = $thumb_id[1];

        // If thumb id is not found, try to look for the image in DB. Thanks to "Erwin Vrolijk" for providing this code.
        if (!$thumb_id) {
            $image = substr($image, strpos($image, '"')+1);
            $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE guid = '".$image."'");
            $thumb_id = $result[0]->ID;
        }

        // Ok. Still no id found. Some other way used to insert the image in post. Now we must fetch the image from URL and do the needful.
        if (!$thumb_id) {
            $thumb_id = apt_generate_post_thumb($matches, $key, $post[0]->post_content, $post_id);
        }

        // If we succeed in generating thumg, let's update post meta
        if ($thumb_id) {
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $thumb_id );
            break;
        }
    }
}
}// end apt_publish_post()
```

Try changing the regex but I had no success.

The solution that might work is to change the url inside the array.

I can change the array? How can I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($matches[0] as $key => &$image) {
    $image = str_replace("_thumb", "", $image);
}
```

Example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/56eb11d00750dc40d87e5b4aee05e64f6b8289a7

Answer (score 0):

The thumbnail is generated using this function I think,

apt_generate_post_thumb()

So we can override it to remove the "_thumb", So that works.

What is the plugin name you are using?